# Good Development setup for Spring-MVC/Hibernate/MySql

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, web-applications, spring-mvc

I'm staring a new project using Spring3-MVC w/ Hibernate and MySql and am envisioning the following development setup:

- Maven
- Eclipse IDE (Having used netbeans in the past, I want to give Eclipse a run)
- Tomcat

**Questions:**

- What will be the life-cycle of development?

  - I've developed struts2 applications with the GF application server and Netbeans IDE in the past. The setup and lifecycle of making a change has been quite slow. Making change to java code, netbeans building code, deploying to GF. I understand these are common points of working with java and webapplication unless I go the Grails way. However, now since there are a few container-less solutions for java web apps - does it make the process a bit fast/east?
- Should I use the embedded Tomcat plugin?
- In netbeans there is a way to add servers and start a maven project by associating the project with the server. Is there something similar in Eclipse?
- Which version of Eclipse should I be downloading?

  - There seem to be [so many](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) I downloaded the javaEE version but it didn't have a way to start a maven project.

Comment: Small suggestion: use the jetty maven plugin to run your app. This plugin will pick up changes done to your jsps automatically. This doesn't happen with the tomcat plugin.

Comment: great tip. thanks. with plugins, however, where would I set my connection settings for the database?

Comment: You can either set up the connection in your app, by reading a property file from spring, or using JNDI. I don't like JNDI as it usually complicates things, but this is because I don't share a connection pool between applications.

Comment: @Augusto the tomcat plugin picks up changes for jsp. Maybe you had a bad version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use embedded tomcat plugin, if you are going with Maven, go with maven tomcat plugin. And deploy your application with:

```
mvn tomcat:run
```

> In netbeans there is a way to add servers and start a maven project by
>   associating the project with the server. Is there something similar in
>   Eclipse?

Yes you can add tomcat server in eclipse, and start/stop tomcat within eclipse, it also allows you to debug easily, by just adding the source projects.

> Which version of Eclipse should I be downloading?

Latest :) Eclipse Juno 4.1 I believe.

For starting on maven project, check the maven [getting-started guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html)

Also, you can use maven plugin for eclipse [m2eclipse](http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse)

Comment: In addition to this answer, I'd use SpringSource ToolSuite.  It's Eclipse based, and comes with maven support out of the box as well as some nice-to-have Spring specific stuff like code completion in Bean XMLs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If starting from scratch I'd recommend using [spring boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).

Regarding eclipse, you should get the version 'for java developers' but not the EE version unless you plan on using glassfish or JBoss or some other EE container. Even if you did need the EE version I'd download and use it separately.

Answer (score -2):

It has been a decade since Microsoft ASP.NET has conquered the entire web application development community.A latest alternative have been developed which is known as ASP .Net MVC development. Model View Controller (MVC) is the new thing in the present era that has caught the fancy of many web development companies.

Comment: Yeah, because MVC is totally an invention from Microsoft and the .NET platform. Microsoft has *not* conquered the "entire web application development community". If any platform or language has even been close, it's PHP with a market share of around 75%. And yes, you can develop with the MVC pattern in PHP.

Comment: Completely unconstructive, doesn't answer the question, and amazingly fanboi-ish.  Downvoted.

Comment: WTF does this have to do AT ALL with what was asked.